# why if i put a large TCP window in iperf returns me a wrong measurement?

Tags: tcp, window, bandwidth, iperf

I want to know how about when I put a huge TCP window in iperf,eg 64MB, not give me errors, but gives me wrong measurement for example 54Mbits/sec in bandwindth and my connection upload is only 1 Mbps. Is it bug of iperf?

i put in command this: iperf -w 64MB -c IPaddress -p and_the_port

and i received this:

### Interval   Transfer  Bandwidth

0.0-10.1sec  65.0MBytes    54.2 Mbits/sec

which is wrong because my connection is:
Bandwidth(Up/Down)[kbps/kbps]: 1.023/15.000

Comment: How do you know your connection bandwidth? Is this set on a bandwidth limiting switch?

Comment: From my router settings, i went to 192.168.1.1 and after to broadband connection, to  DSL connection and Bandwidth(Up/Down)[kbps/kbps]: 1.023/15.000.

Answer (score -1):

Your TCP window size looks to be way too large for your bandwidth. The TCP window size should be just large enough to accommodate the so-called "Bandwidth Delay Product," which is the highest bandwidth of your channel multiplied by the round trip delay time. You should be able to get the round trip time from the BW test you performed.

Ex. 10 Mbps * 98 mS = 0.98 Mbits

Comment: *Lowest* bandwidth of your *path,* multiplied by the *one-way* delay time, actually.

Comment: Yes, i know that is too large. But my question is why didn't give me error, if i put too large TCP window? Is it bug of iperf?

Comment: i found that is something happened with the buffer. thank you all!!